# I changed the primary_key of a model and now it's `ForeignKey` model doesn't work

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a `Post`  model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True, default=random_string)
    has_upvoted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="has_upvoted")
    has_downvoted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="has_downvoted")
```

and a `PostScore` model:

```
class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
```

Because I recently changed the `id` on my `Post` model from the default `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` to the current `CharField`, it's causing this error when I run `migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "post_post_has_downvoted_post_id_3b2ec618_fk_post_post_id" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "post_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Edit:

I'm now getting this `IntegrityError` - I don't why as I have deleted all migration history related to the changes of `id` so it should just go back to normal.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 156, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 256, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_field=field)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 206, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that when you edit PK type from `AutoField` to `CharField` it tries to get new type from old value and fail. If you want to use **UUID**, try using `UUIDField` instead.

To be honest, you should touch the id parameter at all. In case you need to associate unique string with your DB record, I'd suggest you to **add** new field to it

```
local_id = models.CharField(unique=True, mac_length=120)
```

If you still need your string as PK, even if it's not recommended, the most simple way is to delete the database, so it would not need to convert `integer` to `varchar`.

Comment: So are you saying if I want to create a custom primary_key field, I should not call it `id`?

Comment: I'm stating that you should use default PK. If you still need to use your, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Delete DB and create it from scratch

Comment: So are you saying that the only time you can change PK to CharField is when you're starting a new database? I will take your advice and use `local_id` to identify a unique alphanumeric string - in order to keep `id` intact and not cause any problems.

Comment: Exactly. Approve the answer then